# Selenium handling List with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi i have written this code . Now for date part it works as expected but for time part neither it is giving any exception nor it is printing time slots .

URL:-https://www.dineout.co.in/delhi/boa-village-civil-lines-north-delhi-21335

```
WebDriver driver;
String datee="";
String t="";

public RDP(WebDriver ldriver){
    this.driver=ldriver;
}


@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@class='form-control']")
WebElement Time_selector;

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@class='do do-calender-icon']")
WebElement calender;
public void logged_in_user_booking() throws InterruptedException
{
    calender.click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    List<WebElement> dates= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.days li"));

    //System.out.println(dates);
    for(int i=0 ;i<dates.size();i++)
    {
        datee = dates.get(i).getText();
        if(datee.equalsIgnoreCase("31"))
        {

            dates.get(i).click();
            break;
        }

    }

    List<WebElement> time_slots = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.timings-wrap ul li"));
    for(int j=0 ;j<time_slots.size();j++)
    {
         t = time_slots.get(j).getText();
        System.out.println(t);

    /*  if(t.equalsIgnoreCase("03:00 pm"))
        {

            time_slots.get(j).click();
            break;
        }
        */

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time slots take some time to load, so if you didn't set `implicitlyWait` `driver.findElements` won't wait for any element to exist and will return an empty list. Adding `implicitlyWait`, one time right after the `driver` instantiation, should solve this problem (you should add it anyway).

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You can also use explicit wait with [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
List<WebElement> time_slots = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.timings-wrap ul li")));
```